# Как сделать кастомный sidebar для несколько страниц?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, nuxt.js, vuetify

Ситуация такая, есть:

- шаблон по умолчанию `layouts/default.vue`
- **левый sidebar** который присуствует **на все страницы**
- **правый sidebar**, который должен быть только **на несколько страниц**

В `store/index.js` храню переключатель, если `state.sidebar.right === true` то в `layouts/default` показываю кнопку для открытия правого сайдбара.

Теперь проблема в том чтобы при переходе на страницу в которой должен быть сайдбар, загрузить в нём нужные компоненты и в них данные с `API`.

И ещё вопрос, где нужно хранить `<v-navigation-drawer>` чтобы он открылся при клике на кнопку с `layout/default`? Объязательно в `layout/default`? Пробовал хранить его в компоненте страницы (`pages/cat/index.vue`) но не работает. Наверное нужно держать его состояние тоже в `store`, правильно понимаю?

`<nuxt-child>` тоже пробовал использовать но грузиться контент который есть и в `<nuxt>`

Может быть не очень чётко сформулировал проблему, я ещё начинающий.

Comment: А как у вас открывается сайдбар?

Comment: @Plikard при клике на кнопку в layouts/default

Comment: Это я понял. А сам сайдбар скрывается по v-if?

Comment: @Plikard Да, когда он в layout/default, то скрываеться по v-if